# Simplest way to check for basic latin letter (A-Z)

Tags: c#, validation, char

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but is there a simpler way to check if a character is a basic latin letter (a-z) other than converting to a string and using Regex?: For example:

```
public static bool IsBasicLetter(Char c) {
    return Regex.IsMatch(c.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Char.IsLetter matches hundreds of letter characters from many alphabets. I could directly check the code points, but that feels sketchy:

```
public static bool IsBasicLetter(Char c) {
    int cInt = c;
    return !(cInt < 65 || cInt > 122 || (cInt > 90 & cInt < 97));
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your second bit of code looks a lot better if you use character literals:

```
public static bool IsBasicLetter(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}
```

Comment: This surprises me. I would have thought that A < É < Z. When sorting strings it certainly is. But your code does work.

Comment: @jmh_gr: Characters are simply UTF-16 code units, with non-accented characters in the ASCII portion (i.e. less than U+0080).

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
return (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z') || (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z');
```

Comment: Note that it's meant to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

If you ever want to make it a bit more complicated like subset of A-Z and several other characters (i.e. to check for valid Base64 characters) consider using array of Boolean flags for first 127 or 255 characters with `true` for characters you want to allow in your IsBasicLetter method. This is the way most of libraries actually implement this type of functions.

For more Unicode-friendly methods of checking of characters (clearly outside of scope of the question) check out methods of Char class like [IsLetterOrDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit.aspx) which checks for all possible variants of letters.